# "As am I" or "So am I"

Tags: word-choice

I was talking to a friend then she started complain that she was tired. I said "As am I"; later she asked "Don't you mean *So am I*?"

Am I right, or is she right?

Answer (score 1):

You're both right, technically. They're quite similar on the surface and mean exactly the same thing, but "so is [X]" is codified and very common, while "as is [X]" remains formal and archaic. I would take her suggestion and use "so am I" in conversation.